# Why doesn't x increment after x++?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is x after “x = x++”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911776/what-is-x-after-x-x)

In a loop I have:

```
int x = 0;
while(int x < 10){
x = x++;
}
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: By "not work" I'm guessing you mean "x never changes from 0". Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... try this instead.

```
int x = 0;
while(int x < 10){
x++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `x = x++` to just `x++`. `x++` is [unary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation) and you don't need to use the assignment operation.

Answer (score 3):

Post increment operator uses the value first and then increments.

```
x=x++;
```

Here, we assign X to X (zero to zero) and then we increment X to 1 but we never assign it to anything.

you can change to

```
X=++X;
```

and this should give you what you want.

Comment: I disagree with `X=++X`, I think `x = x + 1` or `x++` is a lot clearer!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "we never assign it to anything". ++ acts on the variable itself.

Comment: it is all about the preference man.  X=++X; is used to show the difference between post and pre increment operators. So, i answered the question by providing extra info on an operator which is related to the topic.

Comment: @Bob Kaufman it means the assignment takes precedence over the increment. And X is never incremented in our case (x=x++)

Comment: Well, maybe my wording were confusing. No problem! Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Try converting

```
x = x++;
```

to

```
y = x++; // i.e. y = x, then increment x
x = y;
```

to understand it.

Comment: And that would produce the same result...