# Why java statement evaluation is happening like these ?

Tags: java, post-increment, pre-increment

```
int z = 1;
System.out.println(z++ == ++z);
System.out.println(++z == z++);
```

the output will be:

```
false
true
```

and I don't get why, please explain this to me.

Comment: Duplicate of [explain working of post and pre increment operator in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/explain-working-of-post-and-pre-increment-operator-in-java)

Comment: @DaoWen Not exactly a duplicate - when a statement contains several pre/post increment operators, the order in which each operand is executed is what matters (assuming one understands the difference between a single ++x vs x++). The question you point to uses the additive operator (which happens to also be left-associative), not the equality operator.

Comment: @assylias - I guess that's true. I think "explain working of post and pre increment operator in Java" is a better title for this question though. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You Should Clear About Pre Increment & Post Increment
Lets Have A Look

```
int i=1;
int j=i++;
int k=++i;
```

here in the value of `j` will be `1` and `k` will be `3`

why means in `i++` first store the value `i` into `j` and after which increments the value of `i` so

```
j=1,i=2 ok :)
```

now in the case of `++i` where first increment the value and after that store into `k` so

```
k=3,i=3 ok :)
```

now am coming to your question

```
int z = 1; System.out.println(z++ == ++z);
```

so tell me what will be `z++` ? 1 ok:)
hence `++z` will be ? `3`so the statement will print `false` ok :)
and the second case

```
System.out.println(++z == z++);
```

`++z` will be `4` and `z++` will be `4` so you got  `true`
So hope You Clear...

Comment: thanks jenuine :) i like ur answer the most,you explanation can clear  even a baby too :) thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

[Operands of `==` are evaluated left to right](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21-120), and the `++` has higher priority, so your code is equivalent to:

```
int z = 1;
int tmp1 = z++; //tmp1 = 1 / z = 2
int tmp2 = ++z; //tmp2 = 3 / z = 3
System.out.println(tmp1 == tmp2);

tmp1 = ++z; //tmp1 = 4 / z = 4
tmp2 = z++; //tmp2 = 4 / z = 5
System.out.println(tmp1 == tmp2);
```

I assume you understand the difference between `z++` and `++z`:

- `tmp1 = z++;` can be broken down into: `tmp1 = z; z = z + 1;`
- whereas `tmp2 = ++z;` can be broken down into: `z = z + 1; tmp2 = z;`

Comment: If you're going to break it down and use `tmp` vars to hold the intermediate values, maybe you should show what the pre- and post-increment operators actually expand to.

Answer (score 5):

```
int z = 1;
    System.out.println(z++ == ++z);
    System.out.println(++z == z++);
```

z++ is post increment and ++z is pre-increment. Post increment increases the value after the expression is evaluated and pre increment increase the value before the expression is evaluated.

Hence,

```
int z = 1;
    System.out.println(z++ == ++z); // 1 == 3 false
    System.out.println(++z == z++);// 4 == 4 true
```

Answer (score 3):

the operator `==` gives precedence to what is on its left, in other words since it operates on 2 values, the values on the left is evaluated first.

the operator `++` before the label of the var indicates that the increment is assigned to the value before evaluating it, the same operator putted after the label cause a post-increment, meaning that the value of the variable is incremented by 1 after evaluating it.

regarding the second row of your code:

- the operator `==` looks on its left
- the operator evaluate `z` as `1`
- the operator has done with the left part but an increment is made because of your `z++` that is just saying that, increment after `z` is evaluated, so now `z` is `2` but is evaluated by the `==` operator as `1`, remember that.
- the operator `==` looks on the right
- the operator can't evaluate what is in `z` without making an increment because of `++z`, this means that `z` is evaluated as `3`

1 != 3.

same concepts applies to the next row.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(z++ == ++z); // 1 == 3 is false
System.out.println(++z == z++); // 4 == 4 is true
```

While using post increment value is copied into temporary variable 'tmp', check here [postincrement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12033710/1065180).
So `z++ == ++z` => evaluates to `1 == 3` which is false. Now z is 3.

Coming to 2nd expression : `++z == z++`, again : ++z becomes 4 and in case of z++, value is copied in `tmp` variable and used it at `z++`. Expression becomes `4 == 4` which is true and final value of `z is 5`

Comment: Didn't downvote, however you've added no real explanation as to -why- this happens. Assume the OP doesn't understand pre-inc or post-inc operators. =)

Answer (score 0):

The statement ++z returns the incremented value of z whereas z++ returns its previous value before increment, however the value of z after z++ expression returns is the incremented value of z.

so

```
int z = 1;                                        // Line 1
System.out.println(z++ == ++z);                   // Line 2
System.out.println(++z == z++);                   // Line 3
```

In line 2, z++ returns 1 and value of z is incremented once it returns so z is now 2 and ++z increments the value before returning so z is 3. Therefore line 2 is

```
System.out.println(1 == 3);
```

which is **false**.

In Line 3, ++z evaluates to 4 (since previous value of z is 3) and z++ again returns the previous value of z i.e. 4 but z is 5 now. Therefore Line 3 is

```
System.out.println(4 == 4);
```

which is **true**.