# i and i=i++ in for loop java

Tags: java, for-loop

What is the logic behind this behaviour?

```
 int i=0;
    for(int k=0;k<10;k++){
    i++;
    }
    System.out.println("i="+i);

Output=10; //Exepcted



 int i=0;
    for(int k=0;k<10;k++){
    i=i++;
    }
    System.out.println("i="+i);

Output=0; //Surprised :)
```

Can anybody throw some light on above functionality?

Comment: what? it's the same code

Comment: @Axarydax second version has `i=i++` rather than just `i++`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911776/what-is-x-after-x-x

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See this brilliant answer:

```
x = x++;
```

is equivalent to

```
int tmp = x;
x++;
x = tmp;
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911776/what-is-x-after-x-x).

Comment: anybody trying to understand `x=x++` keep in mind that post-increment has given priority over the assignment and x++ increments but returns old value.

Answer (score 7):

`i = i++` is a postfix increment operator - it increments `i`, then returns it to its original value (because the `i++` essentially "returns" the value of `i` before it was incremented.)

`i = ++i` would work since it's a prefix increment operator, and would return the value of I after the increment. However, you probably just want to do `i++` there without any extra assignment as you do in the first run - it's (essentially) shorthand as it is for `i = i+1`.

Answer (score 5):

What is happening happens because java is pass-by-value.

In the first loop, `i` is getting incremented in the `i++` statement, however, in the second loop what is happening is that `i` gets pointed to a *new* memory location that stores the value of `i` (in this case 0) and then increments the old location.

To visualise:

```
i => 0x00000001 // 0

for() {
    i => 0x00000002 <- 0  // store old i value (0) in new location
    0x00000001++          // Increment the value stored at the old location

    // Cause there is no longer a reference to 0x00000001, 
    // it will get garbage collected and you will be left with
    // i => 0x00000002
```

And it will keep doing that, assigning the old value to a new location and incrementing the old value for each pass of the loop

Answer (score 2):

`i=i++;` will never increment i because the ++ is processed after the i=i.

you could see it like this:

```
int i=0;
for(int k=0;k<10;k++){
    int j = 0;
    i = j;
    j = j + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
i = i++;
```

is equivalent to,

```
int temp = i; // temp = 0
i++; // i=1
i = temp; // i = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The ++ operator is processed **after** the assigment,

if you changed it `i=++i;` you'd probably get the behaviour you expected

Comment: Well yes.  But you shouldn't recommend a bad solution.  Better solutions are `i++;` or `i +=1;` or `i = i + 1;`.

Comment: yes agreed, `i=++i;` would never be used in practice

Answer (score 1):

In the first option , you are incrementing the i by using `i++` , which is equivalent to `i=i+1`, so it increases the value of i to 10.
but in the second option , you are assining i a new value , hence getting the same value everytime.

Answer (score 1):

i=i++;

returns i and increments. so the increment is lost... look at this pseudo code

x = i++ will break the operation in following steps

```
x = i;
i++;
```

in your case , it returns 0 increments to 1 (but the increment is lost)