# Behaviour of PreIncrement and PostIncrement operator in C and Java

Tags: java, c, post-increment, pre-increment

I'm running the following programs in Visual C++ and Java:

**Visual C++**

```
void main()
{
    int i = 1, j;
    j = i++ + i++ + ++i;
    printf("%d\n",j);
}
```

Output:

```
6
```

**Java:**

```
public class Increment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 1, j;
        j = i++ + i++ + ++i;
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
7
```

Why the output in these two languages are different? How both the langauges treat pre and postincrement operators differently?

Comment: In C and C++, the order in which expressions are evaluated and the order in which side effects are applied are *unspecified*; the result will vary from implementation to implementation.  The respective standards leave such behavior *undefined* so that the compiler implementor doesn't have to worry about how to handle such expressions; any result is considered "correct".  Java and C#, OTOH, specify that all expressions are evaluated from left-to-right, and that all side effects are applied immediately, so expressions like this are well-defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C/C++ behavior is undefined because In this expression `i` is modified more then once without an intervening sequence point. read: [What's the value of i++ + i++?](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#evaluation-order)

Of-course in Java behaviour of [this kind of codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911776/what-is-x-after-x-x) is well defined. 
Below is my answer for Java, step by step:

At the beginning `i` is `1`.

```
j = i++ + i++ + ++i;
// first step, post increment
j = i++ + i++ + ++i;
//  ^^^
j = 1   + i++ + ++i;
// now, i is 2, and another post increment:
j = i++ + i++ + ++i;
//  ^^^^^^^^^
j = 1   + 2   + ++i;
// now, i is 3 and we have a pre increment:
j = i++ + i++ + ++i;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
j = 1   + 2   +   4;
j = 7;
```

Comment: your answer is very good for Java, I added for c in your answer, if you don't like roll back to your version.

Answer (score 4):

The C++ example evokes undefined behavior.  You must not modify a value more than once <strike>in an expression.</strike> between sequence points.  [*Edited to be more precise.*]

I'm not certain if the same is true for Java.  But it's certainly true of C++.

Here's a good reference:
[Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: citation please? I've never heard of that... only that it was not recommended.

Comment: @Mgetz: Edited above to add a definitive reference.  Scroll down to "1) Between the previous and next sequence point a scalar object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression."