# Java method()++ VS method()+1

Tags: java

I'm trying to do `Class.Method()++` but it won't work.

Simple example :

**Person Class**

```
public class person {
    private int age;

    public void age(int value) {
        this.age = value;
    }
    public int age() {
        return this.age;
    }
}
```

**In Main Class**

Following statements get an error about `p1.age()++`  :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     person p1 = new person();
     p1.age(p1.age()++); // Get an error
}
```

But below works fine :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
         person p1 = new person();
         p1.age(p1.age()+1); // It works fine
    }
```

**The main question :**

Why `p1.age()++` get error but `p1.age()+1` doesn't ?

**P.S :**

I know i can do this :

```
person p1 = new person();
    int myAge = p1.age();
    p1.age(myAge++);
```

Comment: Did you try `(p1.age())++` instead ?

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly not tried but even if that works it would be so horrible code...

Comment: As an aside: [are you sure `p1.age(myAge++);` would work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911776/what-is-x-after-x-x)?

Comment: (Hint: no it would not...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because

```
x++;
```

is short for

```
x = x + 1;
```

and in your case would be

```
p1.age() = p1.age() + 1; // ERROR
```

and you can't have a method call on the left hand side of an assignment.

Comment: Not quite `x = x+1` would evaluate to the new value of `x`, `x++` evaluates to the old value of `x`.

Comment: `x++` and `x = x + 1` are *not* completely equivalent. There are cases where the first compiles and the second doesn't.

Comment: When you use x++ in a statement, you can treat it as returning x and then incrementing the variable x by 1. You can't increment a constant (like a method return) by 1.

Answer (score 3):

`method()++` means `method() = method() + 1`

which is wrong because you can't assign a value to method

Answer (score 0):

++, the way you used, is a postfix operator.
It will use the value, then increment it.

A method returns a value. Is not a value.

From [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2):

> The result of the postfix expression must be a variable of a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a numeric type, or a compile-time error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

`p1.age` returns a value, but the increment operator ++ reads the value and tries to assign it. Methods cannot take assignments in Java, so you get the compiler error.