# why same code in two technology behaving different

Tags: java, c, post-increment

Below is my code snippet in C.

```
void main(){
 int x = 7;
 x = x++;
 printf("%d",x);
}
```

output : 8

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        int x = 7;

        x =  x++;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

output : 7

i am not getting why both language giving different output.
I've referred below link
[What is x after "x = x++"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911776/what-is-x-after-x-x/7911795#7911795)

Comment: First code snippet is [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in C.

Comment: the exact same post as this famous one!!! [link here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911776/what-is-x-after-x-x?lq=1

Comment: Where does it say they should behave the same?

Answer (score 2):

In java  after x++ there is no change in the value of `x`

x = x++;  equal to

```
int i= x;
x = x + 1;
x = i;
```

so `x`  remains same as *i*

You can read more from here :[Why are these constructs (using ++) undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

Comment: Why this is equivalent to int i= x;
x = x + 1;
x = i; in java not in C

Comment: @RohitKumar Please go through the link attached.

Answer (score 0):

In the second example the assignment first saves the value of x, then sets x to its value plus 1, and,
finally, resets x back to its original value.
Kind of:

```
int temp=x;
x=x+1;
x=temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=x++;
```

This gives arbitrary results in C, mainly depending on compiler. Read about `sequential points` in C. You may refer to `C Programming` by `Dennis ritchie`.