# explain why difference in the same code

Tags: java, c

my code is :

```
 code(){
    int x=7;
    x=x++;
    output x;   //prints 8 in C, prints 7 in Java
 }
```

Guys the above code:  prints **`8`** in **`C`**, and **`7`** in **`Java`** !!

Why is this so? please explain.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993032/why-same-code-in-two-technology-behaving-different

Comment: I think you wanted to say `8` in C **?**

Comment: ^ yes sorry , i meant that

Comment: @anonymous Ok then read my comment to Rohit's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That will print `7` in Java. `x=x++;` is equivalent to :

```
int temp = x;
x = x + 1;  
x = temp;
```

The result would have been different if you would have used *prefix* operator , `++x` .

See for yourself over here: [java code](http://ideone.com/BPHmu5); [C code](http://ideone.com/Y4MDCO).

Read [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc) to comprehend the output in C.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks for that Ideone proof.

Comment: Sir i have run this code.. i have seen this explanation but why this behaviour different in C ? :/

Comment: @anonymous It is not different.

Comment: @anonymous And also read this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc

Comment: @anonymous. The behaviour is undefined in `C`. It can give you different output based on different compilers, and environment.

Comment: @anonymous: Java and C are different languages with different rules, and this is one of those situations where the rules are *very* different.  Java guarantees that all expressions are evaluated left-to-right, and that the side effects of the ++ operators are applied immediately.  C does not make this guarantee, so the result will vary from platform to platform.

Answer (score 6):

In Java, `x=x++`, is evaluated as:

```
int temp = x;
x = x + 1;
x = temp;
```

So, basically there is no change is `x` after that expression.

In `C` however, that expression is an [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Also see [Sequence Points Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point)

Comment: probably his mean to say that his C code printing `8` that is because in his compiler: `x = x++;` beaked in two parts: `x = x;` then  `x = x + 1;`  because of `++`. But yes its compiler dependent in C.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan. Well, yes. That is what I've written in my answer. I've not talked about output in `C`, as it's undefined there. In Java, it's guaranteed to be `7`, while OP said it's `8`.

Comment: check again OP says in Java `7` but in C he is getting `8`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan. Ah! I think he changed it.

Answer (score 5):

This code cause undefined behaviour in C so the result may be any, 7, 8, 15 or Page fault. Why this code give 7, is compiler matter.

Answer (score 1):

In the **Java** background, something like the following occurs (for the `i = i++` statement):

```
int temp = i; // store current value of i  
i = i + 1; // increase i because of i++  
i = temp; // assign to i
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x=x++;
```

This gives arbitrary results in C, mainly depending on compiler. Read about `sequential points` in C. You may refer to `C Programming` by `Dennis ritchie`.

Answer (score 0):

it is because of operator precedence. = has more precedence in C than Java.

Comment: Wrong. This prints 7 in Java. And the precedences are all the same.

Comment: In C, it is compiler-specific, i.e. undefined, while in Java it is defined in the language spec (rhs evaludated completely, including side-effects, before assignment to lhs takes place).