# Why is the result not 1?

Tags: java

```
int m = 0;

m += m++;

System.out.println(m);
```

prints to `0`
but i thought `m` will be post incremented and finally be `1`.
Would someone please explain.

**Note**: i know how post increment works (atleast i think i do :P). But what i am trying to figure out is that when i say `m + = m++` lets assume it means `m = m + m++` which will evaluate `m++` after sending the value of `m`, `0` in this case, and evaluate to `m = 0 + 0` then increment the value of `m` because of the post increment. now if post increment has occured, why is `m` not `1`

Comment: @kark "i thought m will be post incremented and finally be 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int m = 0
```

At this point m is `0`

```
m += m++;
```

Expands to `m=m+(m++)`

`m` returns `0`

`m++` returns the value of m which is `0` and then increments it to `1`

transforming `m+(m++)` into `0+0` (m is `1` a this point)

This is then assigned to `m` resulting in the final value of `m`.

Tip: avoid post-increment when you're touching the value otherwise

Answer (score 4):

`m++` returns `m` then increments it.

Change it to `++m` and you'll see `1`.

For clarity, this question explains it too: [What is x after "x = x++"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911776/what-is-x-after-x-x)

Comment: OP says prints to `0`;

Comment: @TheKojuEffect And so it does, and if it is changed as stated here it will print 1. Your point?

Comment: This doesn't explain what happens with the incremented m in the OP example.

Comment: @eis Of course it does. "`m++` returns `m` then increments it" explains it completely

Comment: @EJP And that doesn't explain anything about the question.

Comment: @Chris This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @TheKojuEffect It *answers* the question.

Comment: i know how post increment works @chris. what i am trying to figure out is that when i say `m + = m++` lets assume it means `m = m + m++` which will evaluate m++ after sending the value of `m`, `0` in this case and evaluate to `m = 0 + 0` then increment the value of `m` because of the post increment. now if post increment has occured, why is `m` not `1`

Comment: @EJP I think he didn't see `+=`, do you?

Comment: @TheKojuEffect No I don't, actually. I think he's just confused about evaluation order.

Comment: @EJP Besides, OP don't want to print `1` but asking why it is not `0`.

Comment: @EJP I think you are clear about my point now.

Comment: While this answer is not incorrect. It does not explain the underlying reasons behind why m == 0 after it 'should' have been incremented according to someone who doesn't know about evaluation order.

Comment: @EJP it does not. If m is incremented, where does the incremented value go?

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following rules:

- `a += b` is equivalent to `a = a + b`. Therefore `m += m++` is equivalent to `m = m + m++`.
  You can see that the first occurence of `m` at the right sight is evaluated before the increment and produces `0`
- `m++` increments `m` and returns original value of `m` before the increment.
  So, in your case `m++` sets `m` to `1` and returns `0`
- Assignment happens after evaluation of the right side, whereas post-increment happens during evaluation of the right side.

Now you can see that your expression is evaluated as follows:

- Evaluation of the right side produces `0` and sets `m` to `1`
- Assignment sets `m` to value of the right side (`0`)

Answer (score 2):

The sequence of events is:

1. The RHS is evaluated (0)
2. The post increment is done (m++).
3. The evaluated result is assigned (m=0 again).

i.e. this is equivalent to:

```
tmp = m;
m++;
m = tmp;
```

If you did m = ++m, the sequence would be:

1. The pre increment is done (++m).
2. The RHS is evaluated (1)
3. The evaluated result is assigned (m=1).

Comment: +1 since your submission came in before mine.

Answer (score 2):

**ANSWER:** An assignment evaluates side effects *before* performing the assignment.

```
m += m++;
```

is equivalent to

```
temp = m + m++;    ; m is now 1, but temp is 0
m = temp;          ; m is now 0 again
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code

`m+ =m++;` Results -- >> M value + (post incremented m value(m++))

Initially

m value= 0

**post incremented(m++) m value = 0 (pre increment(++m) = 1)**

Answer (score 0):

Well m++ return the value of m before to increment it, contrary to ++m that increment then return, like:

```
 int m++(int m){
     int tmp = m;
     m = m+1;
     return tmp; 
}


 int ++m(int m){
     m = m+1;
     return m; 
}
```

Comment: uh... wat is `m++(int m)` by the way..?

Comment: just a barbarism to represent the function behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`f` is your code. `g` is an expanded version showing why they both print `0`.

```
class Test {
    private static void f() {
        int x = 0;
        x += x++;
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    private static void g() {
        int x = 0;
        int preInc = x; // preInc = 0
        x += 1;         // x = 1
        x = preInc;     // x = 0
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        f();
        g();
    }
}
```