# Order of operations in i=i++;

Tags: java, operators

Understanding the difference between `++i` and `i++`, the below example still feels counter-intuitive.
Could someone please explain the order of operations and assignments in the following example?

```
    int i = 0;
    i = i++;
    System.out.println(i); // 0
```

Namely on line two, why is `i` not incremented after the assignment?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911776/what-is-x-after-x-x

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simple way to see it is like this:

Step 1: Your `int i = 0;` line, which (of course) does this:

```
i = 0
```

Then we come to the `i = i++;` line, where things get interesting. The right-hand side of the `=` is evaluated, and then assigned to the left-hand side. So let's look at the right-hand side of that, `i++`, which has two parts:

Step 2:

```
temporary_holder_for_value = i
```

The value of `i` is read and stored away in a temporary location (one of the virtual machine registers, I expect). Then the second part of `i++` is done:

Step 3:

```
i = i + 1
```

Now we're done with the right-hand side, and we assign the result to the left-hand side:

Step 4:

```
i = temporary_holder_for_value
```

The key is that last step. Basically, everything to the *right* of the `=` is done first, and the result of it is then assigned to the left. Because you used a post-increment (`i++`, not `++i`), the result of the expression on the right takes `i`'s value **before** the increment. And then the last thing is to assign that value to the left-hand side.