# Behavior of post increment in java

Tags: java

I know this is a silly example, but I do want to know how it works.
In general, post-increment gives the old value and add 1 to the variable after.

```
int a = 1;
a = a++;
System.out.println(a);
```

At line3, it prints out "1". why does a remain the same?

In my understanding,
At line2, the right hand side assigns 1 to the variable a.

post-increment "++" add 1 to a.
Shouldn't it be 2 instead of 1?

Comment: Think about it.  A temp copy of `a` is made.  Then `a` is incremented.  Then the temp copy is assigned to the assignment target (which happens to be `a`).  Post-increment is a very dangerous function if you don't think it through carefully.  Avoid using it if you can.

Comment: [What is x after “x = x++”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7911776/1391249)

Comment: @HotLicks why not post that comment as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of `a = a++;` (in Java) like this:

```
int tmp = a;
a = a + 1;
a = tmp;
```

**First** the value of `a` is read, then `a` is incremented, but then `a` is assigned the value you read in the first place. This is because the expression `a++` takes the value of `a` *before* the increment. Then, the expression `a = ____` happens, assigning the value you got during the `a++` to `a`.

Answer (score 3):

The assignment happens *after* the increment, using the pre-increment value of `a`.

That's because the sequence of events for post increment is:

- use the current value of the variable
- immediately increment the variable (before any other action)

The effect of the second step is overwritten by the following assignment, which of course uses the ore-increment value as per the first step