# x = x++ doesn't increment because the ++ is applied after the assignment?

Tags: java, scjp, post-increment

From page 280 of OCP Java SE 6 Programmer Practice Exams, question 9:

```
int x = 3;
x = x++;
// x is still 3
```

In the explanation we can read that:

> The `x = x++;` line doesn't leave `x == 4` because the `++` is applied
>   **after** the assignment has occurred.

I agree that `x` is 3, I understand post-incremenation.

I don't agree with the explanation. I would replace *"after"* with *"before"*.

I thought it works like this:

1. `x` is 3.
2. `x++` is executed. I see this post-increment operator as a function:

   ```
   int operator++() {
       int temp = getX();
       setX(temp + 1);
       return temp;
   }
   ```

   So, after `x++` execution, `x` is 4, but the value returned from `x++` expression is `3`.
3. Now, the assignment `=`. Simply write returned `3` to `x`.

So, in my eyes `++` is applied **before** the assignment has occurred. Am I wrong?

Comment: Have you tested it ? Make a simple application and try it out!

Comment: Why don't you simply test it?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911776/what-is-x-after-x-x

Comment: @SvetlinZarev, JBNizet Yes, I tested it, it returns 3. I agree on this with the book. I don't agree about the reason why it is 3.

Comment: Logically you are right. But there isn't any getter setter for int in java and ++ isn't any method

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ...the `++` is applied **after** the assignment has occurred.

Okay, hold on. This is actually confusing and perhaps suggests an incorrect behavior.

You have the expression<sup>†</sup>:

```
x = ( x++ )
```

What happens is ([JLS 15.26.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1)):

1. The expression on the left-hand side of the assignment `x` is evaluated (to produce a variable).
2. The expression on the right-hand side of the assignment `( x++ )` is evaluated (to produce a value).
3. The evaluation of the right-hand side is: `x` is post-incremented, and the result of the expression is the old value of `x`.
4. The variable on the left-hand side, `x`, is assigned the value produced by the evaluation of the right-hand side, which is the old value of `x`.

So the post-increment happens *before* the assignment.

(Therefore, as we know, the value of `x` *after* executing the statement `x = x++;` is the same as the value of `x` *before* executing the statement, which is `3`.)

> So, in my eyes `++` is applied **before** the assignment has occurred. Am I wrong?

You are right.

Technically, the way it is specified is that *`x++` is evaluated before its result is stored and during the evaluation of the assignment operator*. So `x++` can be interpreted as happening either *before* or *during* the assignment. Not *after*, so the book appears to be wrong either way.

Just for the heck of it, we may also look at some bytecode:

```
/*                          int x = 3;                           */
iconst_3 // push the constant 3 on to the stack         : temp = 3
istore_0 // pop the stack and store in local variable 0 : x = temp
/*                          x = x++;                             */
iload_0  // push local variable 0 on to the stack       : temp = x
iinc 0 1 // increment local variable 0 by 1             : x = x + 1
istore_0 // pop the stack and store in local variable 0 : x = temp
```

The `iinc` happens before the `istore`.

<sub>†: The parentheses have no effect on the evaluation, they are just there for clarity.</sub>

Comment: Hehe, is there any way to perform assignment before right hand side execution? I don't think so... It should be natural for everyone;)

Comment: @energizer Indeed, we must know a value before it can be assigned.

Answer (score 2):

Reaching over to the official spec:

1. postfix ++ section: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2
2. assignment operator section: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1

In terms of assignment, this is simple assignment, so we hit case 3:

1. First, the left-hand operand is evaluated to produce a variable -- `x`
2. no errors -> the right-hand operand is evaluated -- `x++`
3. "the value of the right-hand operand is converted to the type of the left-hand variable, is subjected to value set conversion (§5.1.13) to the appropriate standard value set (not an extended-exponent value set), and the result of the conversion is stored into the variable"

So in step 2, the postfix operator should get resolved, and then in step 3, x gets assigned its original value again:

```
call: x = x++;
interframe: LHS is variable 'x'
interframe: RHS caches return value as 3
interframe: x is incremented to 4
interframe: RHS cached value '3' is returned for assignment
interframe: variable x is assigned value 3
call result: x = 3
```

So I think you're right in that the book is wrong, and it might be worth contacting the authors or publisher to have a correction published (or added to an errata page, etc)

Answer (score 0):

x++ means "use x and then increment x."

You can also use ++x, which means "increment x and then use x."

More easily, however, you can simply do

```
x += 1;
```

Answer (score -2):

++x is called preincrement while x++ is called postincrement.

```
int x = 3;
x = ++x;
```

exemple

```
int x = 5, y = 5;

System.out.println(++x); // outputs 6
System.out.println(x); // outputs 6

System.out.println(y++); // outputs 5
System.out.println(y); // outputs 6
```

Comment: the question is about the postfix operator, and whether the book's explanation is true or not.

Comment: by the exemple he can dedicate that the book is right.

Comment: no he can't, he's asking about the execution order of operands during assignment, which is not a thing you can test in the language itself.