# Java for loop output

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, conditional-statements, increment

```
import java.io.*;
public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a=0, b=6, sum;
        for(int i=0; i<=2; i++) {
            System.out.println(i=i++);
        }
    }
}
```

Output: `0 | 1 | 2`. But actually I think it should be `0 | 2`. Please explain why I am wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You increment i two times.

Comment: Just print System.out.println(i); works here

Comment: i++ is executed AFTER the assigning of i to i, so that augmentation is lost.

Comment: the assigning of `i = i++` basicly is the same as `i = i`.

Comment: @Karbos yes, she knows. she is asking why it DOESN'T increment twice.

Comment: just replace your code `i=i++` to `i`, this is happening because you increment you variable `i` twice --> `i++` and `i=i++` .

Comment: @SaviNuclear: again: no. you don't understand the question right. She wants to know why it doesn't increment twice, while she did code it to do so.

Comment: [here](http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/how-does-postfix-increment-operator-work-with-assignment/7) is a little link that might help aswell

Comment: Stultuske, yes so after it prints i, then it increments. So next when it goes to for loop increment, it would have already incremented, plus another increment right?

Answer (score 3):

The difference is in this line of code:

```
System.out.println(i=i++);
```

i++ is a post increment, meaning it is only executed after the rest of the statement.

so, it goes a bit like this:

```
System.out.println(
  int tempI = i;
  i = tempI;
  tempI = i + 1;
  );
```

In the end, you print the value of i, while the value of tempI is not used after that, so considered lost.

Comment: That's wrong interpretation. Can you try executing this `{
          i=i++;
             System.out.println(i);
         }`  ?

Comment: Suresh: it's still the same. only, here the i will be augmented BEFORE he print statement is reached. 
I used tempI as an example of the logic, not of how the actual code is.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is in byte code generated for above code. It store back the old value of i into i. Therefore i=i++  statement make no impact logically.

```
iconst_0
istore_1
goto 11
getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
iload_1
iinc 1 1
dup
istore_1
invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(I)V
iinc 1 1
iload_1
iconst_2
if_icmple 4
return
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
{
  System.out.println(i=i++);  //here the value of i is incremented after it is assigned to i.
}
```

When you are doing `i=i++` then `i` is incremented after the assignment. And hence you are not getting as expected.

You can use pre-increment operator and see the difference.

```
for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
{
   System.out.println(i=++i);  
}
```

Here is a related thread which will help you: [What is x after “x = x++”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911776/what-is-x-after-x-x)

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to test it out by yourself actually even without using a debugger.

```
    int a=0,b=6, sum;
    for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i=i++);
        System.out.println("Value of i:" + i);
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
0
Value of i:0
1
Value of i:1
2
Value of i:2
```

**Question:**
So why after `System.out.println(i=i++);`, value of `i` is not increasing?

**Answer:** This is because `i++` means post-increment. The `i` at the right hand side will **only** increase by one **after** that line.

```
//Let say i is 0.
i = i++;
```

i++ means the right hand side `i` will still be 0 till it goes to next line. Hence 0 was assigned to the `i` at the left hand side.

Comment: then in SOP(i=i++), value of i should increase after this line. so after compiler printing this, it then goes to for loop increment, so here the 'i' must have incremented it right? and, then again i increment it in for loop, so basically it is incrementing it twice, i guess.

Comment: @Ashley Your statement is true only if you use a different variable on the RHS. Example: `i + b++`. You print `b` after that it will give you 7. But If you use the same variable on LHS and RHS (i.e. `i = i++`), you assigned the old value back to itself. After that, the i++ is disregarded. This is how Java designed it for post increment. Different from C++.

Answer (score 0):

If this works:.

```
for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
{
    System.out.println(i=++i);
}
```

Because this does not work?:

```
for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
{
    System.out.println(i=i++);
}
```

Apparently the postincrement in the `println` method is treated differently.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this snippet:

```
for (int i=0; i<=2;i+=2){
        System.out.println("i= "+ i);
    }
```

this should give you a short way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is an undefined behaviour in C or C++ if you write:

```
i = i++;
```

Reason being that the order of evaluation cannot be determined. Hence if you write this in C or C++, there is no guarantee what will be produced.

In **Java**, this kind of ambiguity is removed from the design. The order of evaluation is as follows:

```
i = i++;    //value of i++ is stored (0 is stored in this case)
            //i increased by 1, i is now 1
            //The stored value assigned back to i (0 assigned to i)
```

Comment: @ashley Take a look, this solution should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, it made sense. Good day (y)