# Operator ++ used in java for the cycle for()

Tags: java, for-loop

i have a question because i don't find any document that can confirm this:
i am taking an example of ++ operator but it can be the same for the other.

first for-loop:  LOOP

```
for(int i=0 ; i < 5; ) {
  i = i++; 
  System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

second for-loop: 5 iteration

```
for(int i=0 ; i < 5; i++) {
  i = i++; 
  System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

**My question is : 
the operator ++ is acting in one way when we asign it to other variable ???
and it act in another way when we use it inside a for-loop ?**

Rules to excute:

```
for(int i=0; i < 5 ; i++) {

  //some code here to excetute
}
```

order of execution:

- int i= 0
- i < 5
- //execute the code in the body
- operator of update   ( i++)

Thanks to all.

Comment: Do you know what `i++` means? Do you then know what `i = i++` means?

Comment: `i = i++` probably does not do what you think it's doing.

Comment: And about your question: No, `i++` acts the same, no matter if it is inside or outside of a loop.

Comment: [What is x after “x = x++”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911776/what-is-x-after-x-x)

Answer (score 2):

#### Here's an example:

```
int x = 5;
int y = x++;
```

*The result at this point is `y = 5` and `x = 6`.*

#### Why?

`x++` is a *post-increment* operator: `x` itself is incremented, but the **value of the expression** (think return value of sorts) is the original value.

In contrast, `++x` is a *pre-increment* operator: `x` itself is incremented and the value of the expression is the resulting value.  Hence if you do `y = ++x` instead, `y` and `x` will result in the same value.

Comment: Hi antak, your  answer is correct when you are using an operator = that has a lower precedence.

Answer (score -1):

i just found the response in this article:

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/

```
for(int i=0; i<5;)
  i = i++;
}
```

it is a post-increment operator so the Associativity is Left-To-Right.
i++ in it's left has an the operator = .
Cause of Associativity ( and not the level of Precedence ) i assign the value of the i in the right to the variable i in the left. After doing this i do the increment but it doest have a reference variable whent o go for the moment so it remain in the memory for the next row of code that will call the i variable.

**Precedence of operator:**

```
hightl level of precedence is ++
lower level of precedence is =
```

**Associativity of the operator:**

```
Left to Right for the operator ++
Right to left for the operator =
```

So:
java will read all the line with the text till when java will found the semicolon (;). After finding a semicolon (;) java will call this a statement and will go for first to understand the operator and the variable that has inside.
Java see that it has 2 operators , one is ++ and the other one is =.
Cause of precedence the operator ++ will decide the associativity.

So the operator ++ has the associativity from Left to Right. 
So:

```
  i++  (Left to Right)    ---------------->  (execute everything before i for first)
  ++1  ( Right to Left )  <---------------   (execute everything after i for first)
```

i++ will calculate first what will be in the left and later it will go in the right.

- i++  will execute everything in the left first   (..  i)++ till i
  found another operator with hight precedenze that will change the
  direction of the flow cause of level precedence.
- The next operator is = and it is with lower level of precedence so i
  will execute what the operator ++ was saying. For this reason i
  valutate ( i = i ).
- After assign the  ( i = i ) i dont have other operator and i will
  turn back the controlo to the operator ++ so i will execute the
  remain. For this reason i increment of 1 value the i variable.

Comment: To all the people that is continuing to do -1 for my question you are pleased to not read this post and to go away.

The question that i have done is in one of the exam for Oracle Certification.
It has to do with the operator , level of Precedence and Association of operators.
With my question i was trying to understand something by myself and maybe trying to help some other people.
To all the people that is puting -1 please live a comment so we can have a discution about the argument and i can understand my wrong in the excersise.
Best regards

Comment: I think the question is fine, as any C++ programmer will confirm that this is not trivial, but I downvoted the answer because I think it is confusing and maybe even partially incorrect. Some of the sentences don't make a lot of sense, it would help if you (had someone) proofread it and clarified. Something like `++1` is not even legal and `i = i` is never evaluated. In contrast, the other answer (which I upvoted) very concisely answers the question as you asked it, the only thing that might be added, as you noted in a comment, is that it works because the `=` operator has the lowest precedence