# For loop is not giving values as per range

Tags: java

```
       for(OPV=230;OPV<245;OPV++)
       {
           for(IKW=1.3;IKW<=2.9;IKW++)
           {
               for(OKW=0.01;OKW<0.50;OKW++)
              {
                     for(OPI=0.05;OPI<0.50;OPI++)
                     {
                           OPV=OPV+1;
                           IKW=IKW++;
                           OKW=OKW++;

                           System.out.println( OPV+""+IKW+"+OKW+"+OPI")
```

My for loop is not giving me result as per the ranges I have given.suggest some modifications if any

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: What ranges do you think you have given? **How** does this not meet your expectations?

Comment: It is giving me only 1st value from the given range

Comment: @Abdelhak I have already declared that before loop

Comment: `IKW=IKW++;` is wrong

Comment: What range of values do you want `for(IKW=1.3;IKW<=2.9;IKW++)` to represent? Do you want `1.3`, `1.4`, ..., `2.8`, `2.9`? Or only `1.3`, `2.3`?

Comment: `IKW=IKW++;` does nothing.

Comment: @Pshemo yes I want like 1.3,1.4 till 2.9

Comment: Then why are you using `IKW++` to increment its step? It is almost same as `IKW = IKW + 1` not `IKW = IKW + 0.1`.

Comment: Also about `IKW=IKW++` read [What is x after “x = x++”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911776/what-is-x-after-x-x)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you increment the loop variable with `OPI++`, it is incremented by one. This means that the two inner most loops will have just one iteration.

You can set a smaller increment with, for example, OPI+=0.01, depending on your requirements.

Besides that, usually there's no point in incrementing the loop variables inside the loop body as you do, since that causes them to be incremented in both the loop's increment clause and the loop body.

Something like this may be what you want (though you may want to change the increments) :

```
for(OPV=230;OPV<245;OPV++) {
    for(IKW=1.3;IKW<=2.9;IKW+=0.1) {
        for(OKW=0.01;OKW<0.50;OKW+=0.01) {
            for(OPI=0.05;OPI<0.50;OPI+=0.01) {
                System.out.println(OPV + " " + IKW + " " + OKW + " " + OPI);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i did that but it is exceeding value from range for opi