# Application freezes when the second button gets pressed

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a windows Form app In C#.
It is for a course I follow.

Now I have a

> Cannot evaluate expression because a native frame is on the top of the call stack.

error. I have 10 buttons, with a for loop connected to it. The app has 10 buttons and each button show math tables (1 to 10) to Label2. The first button works like a charm. The other buttons give me the expression error.

Here I have the code for the first 2 buttons:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear Label before execution
        label2.Text = "";

        // Loop
        for (int n = 0; n < 11; n++)
        {
            int nn = n * 1;
            label2.Text += "1x" + n + "=" + nn + "\r\n";                
        }

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // Clear Label before execution
        label2.Text = "";

        // Loop
        for (int n = 0; n < 11; n = n++)
        {
            int nn = n * 2;
            label2.Text = "2x" + n + "=" + nn + "\r\n";                                             
        }            

    }
```

Can you guys help me out on this one? I already read through thread handling and such, but I am not that far yet into C#.

Edit: Got it to work with a change in the loop,

From

```
for (int n = 0; n < 11; n = n++)
```

To

```
for (int n = 0; n < 11; n++)
```

Comment: Just a general pointer, but you should give your variables meaningful names. It is very unclear what `nn` is supposed to be, for example.

Comment: Also setting a break point, running the debugger and stepping through your code can do wonders.

Comment: It is not clear what you did to get the debugger to break.  Not likely with a breakpoint if a native frame is on the top of the stack, required.

Comment: Probably using the "Break All"  feature in Visual Studio. I use it frequently to find out where the infinite loop is.

Comment: That can not be the only change to get it working. You also need to change the `label2.Text = .. ` to `label2.Text += ... ` to get it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `n = n++` to just `n++` in your second loop.

Comment: Does not work, I want the outputs of 2x1 till 2x10. With this fix I only get 2x10=20...

Comment: then post how you got it working for others with the same problem

Comment: This will not fix all of his problems. He also needs to change `label2.Text = ...`to `label2.Text += ... `I Tested it in my answer and then it works. Without this change he will only see the last update

Answer (score 2):

Yepp...  `n = n++` is doing nothing.

It's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7911791/9558012).

Comment: It does something, when I only use n++ I only get one output (2x10) I want all the outputs printed to the Label2.

Answer (score 0):

First your loop should have `n++` in stead of `n = n++`
Second you do not concatinate your label text.

it should be

```
label2.Text += ...
```

in stead of

```
label2.Text = ...
```

Comment: The Label2.Text +=, I know. The n++ option does not work. When I only have n++ it will only print out the last sum... (2x10) I want the button to print out every sum...

Comment: that is because you only wrote the last one in the label, the += should fix that

Comment: I have tested and with my adjustments it works like a charm