# Phone Call Programming Logic

Tags: java, logic

Some phone usage rate may be described as follows:

> The first minute of a call costs `min1` cents.
>
> Each minute from the 2nd up to 10th (inclusive) costs `min2_10` cents each minute.
>
> After the 10th minute, the call costs `min11` cents for every additional minute.
>
> You have `s` cents on your account before the call. What is
>   the duration of the longest call (in minutes rounded down to the
>   nearest integer) you can have?

Input data:

For `min1 = 3`, `min2_10 = 1`, `min11 = 2`, and `s = 20`, the output should be `phoneCall(min1, min2_10, min11, s) = 14`.

Here's why:

The first minute costs 3 cents, which leaves you with 20 - 3 = 17 cents.  The total cost of minutes 2 through 10 is 1 * 9 = 9, so you can talk 9 more minutes and still have 17 - 9 = 8 cents. Each next minute costs 2 cents, which means that you can talk 8 / 2 = 4 more minutes.
Thus, the longest call you can make is 1 + 9 + 4 = 14 minutes long.

I'm not sure what's wrong with my code's logic here.

```
int phoneCall(int min1, int min2_10, int min11, int s) {
    int sum = 0;

    if (s >= min1) {
        sum++;
        s = s - min1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            if (s >= min2_10) {
                sum = sum++;
                s = s - min2_10;
            } else
                break;
        }
        sum = sum + s / min11;

    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: you can simplify your life a lot by making a sub-method int totalMinutesPossible(rate, money, maxMinutes). Run this over each phone charge segment consecutively (subtracting what you needed to pay for the previous segment) until you run out of money.

Answer (score 2):

In the if statement inside of your for loop you can do one of two things here to get your return to be 14.

Change the
    `sum=sum++;` to 
    `sum += 1;` or remove the 
    `sum=` so it its just 
    `sum++;`

This should return 14 as the sum.

Comment: lol yea i didn't noticed ..thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
            sum=sum++;
```

should be replaced with `sum++;`

Read more about operator precedence [operator precedence and return values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911776/what-is-x-after-x-x)

Answer (score -1):

Hello @ShubhamSahay You gotta make your code like this:

```
public static int phoneCall(int min1, int min2_10, int min11, int s) {
int sum=0;

if(s>=min1)
{
    sum++;
    s=s-min1;
    for(int i=1;i<=9;i++)
    {
        if(s>=min2_10)
            {
            /*Change 1*/ sum++;
            s=s-min2_10;
            }
        else
            break;
    }
    /*Change 2*/ sum=sum+(s/min11);             

} 
return sum;
}
```

So here is why
1st Change: You need to do just sum++
2nd Change: you gotta put those that things in brackets

Comment: If you're going to downvote, please add a comment..