# Problem in counting the longest sorted sub-sequence in an array

Tags: java

I have a problem in execution of a java program which counts the longest sorted array but the result is always equal to initial value `max = 1`, **where can be the problem?**

```
package longestsortedsquence;

public class Longestsortedsquence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arry={3,98,274,943,23,56,23,4};
        System.out.print(longestsortedsequence(arry));
    }

    public static int longestsortedsequence(int[] arry){
        if(arry==null){
            return 0;
        }
        int max=1;
        int len=1;
        for(int i=0;i<arry.length-1;i++){
            if(arry[i]<=arry[i+1]){
                len=len++;
            }
            else{
                len=1;
            }
            if(max<len){
                max=len;
            }
        }

        return max;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `len=len++;`

Use `len++;` only instead.

You can see explanation for this here : [What is x after "x = x++"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911776/what-is-x-after-x-x)

Answer (score 1):

`len++` will return `len`, and the side effect of that function increase 1 to`len`.
You should use `len++` or `len=++len`, but the second option is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

problem is len

```
package longestsortedsquence;

public class Longestsortedsquence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arry={3,98,274,943,23,56,23,4};
        System.out.print(longestsortedsequence(arry));
    }

    public static int longestsortedsequence(int[] arry){
        if(arry==null){
            return 0;
        }
        int max=1;
        int len=1;
        for(int i=0;i<arry.length-1;i++){
            if(arry[i]<=arry[i+1]){
                len=len++;<---- change it to `len++`
            }
            else{
                len=1;
            }
            if(max<len){
                max=len;
            }
        }

        return max;
    }
}
```